# no boot options

Tags: boot, usb, dvd

I am running on Ubuntu (I was on W8 before), but I need to go back to Windows. 
I'm trying to boot from a live-DVD and a FlashDrive, but without luck.
Ubuntu doesn't give me any boot option. If I press Esc at the startup screen, i only get this options:

*Ubuntu
Advances Options
EFI/ubuntu/MokManager.efi
efi/EFI/ubuntu/MokManager.efi
System setup

I have an Acer Aspire v5-571.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu cannot boot your install media. It's up to your UEFI or BIOS to do so - You will need to get into a boot menu or the UEFI/BIOS itself to boot from USB/DVD. Hardware vendors implemented different ways to get into UEFI/BIOS (most of the time different keystrokes). So, you will need to browse Acer's support pages (or use Google) to find out how to get into your UEFI/BIOS' boot menu.

Comment: thanks! I tried entering the  EFI/ubuntu/MokManager.efi  but it doesn't give any options. it only says:  error: file"efi/EFI/ubuntu/MokManager.efi" not found.  Any idea?

Comment: As said, you're looking into the wrong direction. Whatever `EFI/ubuntu/MokManager.efi` is, it's a file - But you need to enter your **hardware's** UEFI. It's in **no way** related to Ubuntu. I'm pretty sure you are not pressing ESC at the "start up screen" but rather at a point in the boot process when it's too late. Look up how to enter UEFI/BIOS on Acer devices.